# Android 11: Tried to access UI constants from a non-visual Context

Tags: java, android

I was running project OnmiNotes on Github when I ran, and looking at Logcat, the result was an error: "Tried to access UI constants from a non-visual Context", I found out that this is a new error on android 11, and there are quite a few suggestions to correct this error on gg, I look at them, those cases are not suitable for my case. And the person who wrote this app wrote on android 8, so they probably didn't know this error. Below are the code lines I find relevant.
There is an error in Logcat:

```
Tried to access UI constants from a non-visual 
Context:it.feio.android.omninotes.OmniNotes@e9ea0eUI constants, such as 
display metrics or window metrics, must be accessed from Activity or 
other visual Context. Use an Activity or a Context created with 
Context#createWindowContext(int, Bundle), which are adjusted to the 
configuration and visual bounds of an area on screen
```

and:

```
Tried to access visual service WindowManager from a non-visual Context:it.feio.android.omninotes.OmniNotes@e9ea0e Visual services, such as WindowManager, WallpaperService or LayoutInflater should be accessed from Activity or other visual Context. Use an Activity or a Context created with Context#createWindowContext(int, Bundle), which are adjusted to the configuration and visual bounds of an area on screen.
```

And there are two command lines I see mentioned in logcat error
1.In BaseActivity:

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Forces menu overflow icon
    try {
      ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this.getApplicationContext()); //ERROR IN LOGCAT IN THIS LINE
      @SuppressLint("SoonBlockedPrivateApi") Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
      if (menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LogDelegate.w("Just a little issue in physical menu button management", e);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
```

2. MainActivity

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//ERROR IN LOGCAT IN THIS LINE
    setTheme(R.style.OmniNotesTheme_ApiSpec);

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);

    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    Prefs.getPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    initUI();

    if (IntroActivity.mustRun()) {
      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IntroActivity.class));
    }

  }
```

Does anyone know how to deal with it? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `this.getApplicationContext()` and `getApplicationContext()` with `this`. `this` appears to be an `Activity` in both places.

Comment: Thank UUUUUUUUU very much. You save my day :3